# Demodulation of a BFSK frequency hopping signal using FFT

Tags: fft, software-implementation, demodulation

I am not very familiar with DSP techniques, and I am currently working on my research project to develop the firmware of a DSP processor, using C/Linux. It involves the modulation and demodulation of a dataset using Binary FSK and frequency hopping Tx and Rx algorithms. I am able to modulate the signals and have verified the output using MATLAB. However I an a little stuck at demodulation.

The technique that I am using for demodulation is to compare the amplitude of the FFT of the signal received at every hopping sequence and based on that, determine whether the bit received is 1 or 0. I have a predefined function which is used calculate the FFT of the signals. The function is as follows:

```
void fft(complex_float* in, complex_float* out, int N, int inv)
{
int i, j;
float a, f;
complex_float s, w;
f = inv ? 1.0/N : 1.0;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
s.re = 0;
s.im = 0;
for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
  a = -2*PI*i*j/N;
  if (inv) a = -a;
  w.re = cos(a);
  w.im = sin(a);
  s.re += in[j].re * w.re - in[j].im * w.im;
  s.im += in[j].im * w.re + in[j].re * w.im;
}
out[i].re = s.re*f;
out[i].im = s.im*f;
}
}
```

`complex_float` is a predefined struct :

```
typedef struct {
float re;
float im;
}complex_float;
```

In the function `fft()` `N` defines the number of FFT points.

The problem that I am facing is how to determine the frequency points of the individual elements in the array returned by `fft()` function. In MATLAB, this was very easy to do the FFT function in MATLAB took the sampling frequency in account and plotted the power spectrum accordingly. However, In the `fft()` function defined above there is no frequency involved and hence I am confused as to how to find the power of the signal at any particular frequency, or how to determine the frequency point of any element of the retuned array.

Comment: Pedantic note: the code that you showed above is not an [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform). Instead, it's a basic implementation of the [DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform). The FFT is just a fast, clever way to execute a DFT.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different kinds of frequency-hopped BFSK systems.

- In *slow* frequency-hopping, the center frequency or carrier frequency $f_c$ changes periodically at a fraction of the data rate. Thus, the carrier frequency *hops* to a particular value, say $f_1$ and stays there for some time (say $nT$
  seconds, where the bit duration is $T$ seconds.  During this epoch of duration
  $nT$ seconds, $n$ data bits are transmitted successively using BFSK. That is, 
  one of two tones at frequencies $f_1 + \Delta f$ and $f_1 - \Delta f$ is transmitted for a duration of $T$ seconds depending on whether a $0$ or a $1$ is being transmitted. Usually, $\Delta f$ is chosen so that $(2\Delta f)T$ is an
  integer.  Then, the next bit is transmitted over the next $T$ seconds, and so on till a total of $n$ bits have been transmitted.  After $n$ bits have been transmitted, the carrier frequency hops to some other choice $f_2$, and tones 
  at frequencies $f_2 + \Delta f$ and $f_2 - \Delta f$ are used.
- In *fast* frequency-hopping systems, a single bis is transmitted over
  multiple hops, say $m$ hops.  To transmit a $1$, a succession of tones
  of duration $T/m$ are transmitted 
  at frequencies $f_1 - \Delta f$, $f_2 - \Delta f$, $f_3 - \Delta f$, and so on. Of course, if $0$ were to be transmitted, the tones would be at
  frequencies $f_1 + \Delta f$, $f_2 + \Delta f$, $f_3 + \Delta f$.
  Fast frequency hopping systems thus automatically
  provide both frequency diversity and time diversity.

It is easiest to demodulate a frequency-hopped BFSK signa;
by first  *heterodyning* it (see, for example, 
[this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/34351/8157) 
on another stackexchange site) down to a fixed intermediate frequency $f_i$
(so that the tones are at $f_i + \Delta f$ and  $f_i - \Delta f$
regardless of the original frequency of transmission.  This
requires a local tunable oscillator synchronized to the hopping
pattern and offset from the carrier frequencies in the
pattern by frequency $f_i$. After heterodyning, a standard
BFSK receiver can be used, and as David Rick says in another
answer, using a FFT is *not* a particularly good solution
to the problem.  A standard coherent or noncoherent FSK
receiver will be much better to use.

Answer (score 2):

At some point, before the fft() function is called, the sampling frequency must be known (from ADC? or other resampling functions?)... use that to find the frequencies of the bins as you would in Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

The FFT is very inefficient for demodulating BFSK, because you are only using 2 of N bin values, and all the math for the rest is wasted. The Goertzel algorithm is a commonly-used alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the help David, that was really helpful and i can see a the performance improvement with the Goertzel algorithm.